# Find the closest index with "True" and calculating the distance (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

| idx | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | False | False |
| 1 | False | True | False |
| 2 | True | False | True |
| 3 | False | False | False |
| 4 | True | False | True |

I'd like to create three new columns with the distance (from each row) of the closest True, and if that row has a True show 0, so I would get this:

| idx | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | distV1 | distV2 | distV3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | False | False | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | False | True | False | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | True | False | True | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | False | False | False | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | True | False | True | 0 | 3 | 0 |

I have read all other discussions related to this topic but haven't been able to find an answer for something like this.

Comment: For `Var1`, row 1, which True do you pick? The previous one or the next one? They're both equally near.

Comment: @richardec So it does not matter?

Comment: Since both are at the same distance, any of them will do. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach with numpy ops:

```
for c in df:
    r = np.where(df[c])[0]
    d = abs(df.index.values[:, None] - r)
    df[f'{c}_dist'] = abs(df.index - r[d.argmin(1)])
```

---

```
print(df)

    Var1   Var2   Var3  Var1_dist  Var2_dist  Var3_dist
0   True  False  False          0          1          2
1  False   True  False          1          0          1
2   True  False   True          0          1          0
3  False  False  False          1          2          1
4   True  False   True          0          3          0
```

Comment: Great. Works like a charm. Thank you. Now I need to study and understand what those 3 lines do so I understand the logic behind them and also because this solution might stop working soon: 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py:839: FutureWarning: Support for multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead

Comment: Check the edit to remove the warning message. We have to replace `df.index` with either `df.index.values` or `df.index.to_numpy()`

Answer (score 2):

### Code

#### Fill the distance to the nearest `True` position in a column.

```py
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
    
array = df.to_numpy()
bmp = array.astype(np.uint8)
distance = []
for points in bmp.T:
    all_points = np.argwhere(points!=2)
    true_points = np.argwhere(points==1)
    tree = KDTree(true_points)
    dist = tree.query(all_points, k=1, p=2)[0]
    distance.append(dist)
distance = np.array(distance).astype(int).T
df[df.columns + "_dist"] = distance
```

#### Output

```
      Var1   Var2   Var3  Var1_dist  Var2_dist  Var3_dist
idx                                                      
0     True  False  False          0          1          2
1    False   True  False          1          0          1
2     True  False   True          0          1          0
3    False  False  False          1          2          1
4     True  False   True          0          3          0
```

#### Fill the distance to the nearest `True` position in the whole table.

```py
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

array = df.to_numpy()
bmp = array.astype(np.uint8)
all_points = np.argwhere(bmp!=2)
true_points = np.argwhere(bmp==1)
tree = KDTree(true_points)
distance = tree.query(all_points, k=1, p=1)[0]
distance.resize(array.shape)
df[df.columns + "_dist"] = distance.astype(int)
```

### Output

```
      Var1   Var2   Var3  Var1_dist  Var2_dist  Var3_dist
idx                                                      
0     True  False  False          0          1          2
1    False   True  False          1          0          1
2     True  False   True          0          1          0
3    False  False  False          1          2          1
4     True  False   True          0          1          0
```

### Explain

1. Using `np.array` to make `0,1` data

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

2. `argwhere` will return the position coordinate for eligible points.
3. `KDTree` is a classical algorithm to find the nearest point.

   1. arg `k` means the top n nearest points
   2. arg `p`=1 means **"Manhattan" distance**

   > Which Minkowski p-norm to use.
   >
   > 1 is the sum-of-absolute-values distance ("Manhattan" distance).
   >
   > 2 is the usual Euclidean distance.

### Reference

[scipy.KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html)

Comment: I think instead of `df[[c+"_dist" for c in df.columns]]` you can just do `df[df.columns + "_dist"]`

Comment: I'm probably missing something but why is the last row from the new array [0, 1, 0] instead of [0, 3, 0]? Is that code assuming that the last row is next to the first row?

Comment: @CarlosOrtegaGonzález sorry， maybe I misunderstood the meaning of the questioner, here the distance is not just in a row or column, it’s the whole table. I’ll check it later.